# $c_nX_n \overset{P}\to 0 \Rightarrow c_n\to0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables and let $\{c_n\}$ be a real sequence so that $\mathbf{P}(|X_n|>0)>0\;\forall n$ and $c_nX_n \overset{P}\to 0$. Does it hold that $c_n\to0$?

Answer (score 3):

NO. Take $c_n=n$ and $X_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}}$.